# как из переменной класса 'bs4.element.resultset' вытащить данные по ключу

Tags: python, парсер

после парсинга страницы

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, 'html.parser')
items = soup.find_all('form', {"id":"command"})
```

переменная items имеет класс  'bs4.element.resultset',
в ней находится все что находилось в теге form с id command.

Там есть данные :

```
[{"title" : "холодильник", "price" : "100 руб" , "цвет" : "белый"} ,
{"title" : "стиральная машина", "price" : "200 руб" , "цвет" : "черный"},
{"title" : "миксер", "price" : "50 руб" , "цвет" : "красный"}]
```

Похоже на список словарей, но если проверить методов len(items) то результат - 1. 
Тоесть в переменной items всего один элемент.

Мне надо сделать выборку по ключу title. Но title - это не тег, а текст. Как это сделать,что бы все данные после title заносились в словарь и в список?

Должен быть сформирован список такого типа:

```
холодильник
стиральная машина
миксер
```

[
                        {"response":{"cheap":"0","expensive":"0","items":[{"productIndex":"0","sku":"KA90IVI20R","type":"shop","title":"Холодильник Side by Side","isInComparison":false,"comparable":true,"productsInComparisonSize":0,"headers":["iQ500","Холодильник Side by Side","","177 x 91 cm","Inox-easyclean","KA90IVI20R"],"price":{"value":120443.0,"displayValue":"111 111,00 ₽"},"stockStatus":{"trafficLight":"green","text":"[G11]","buyable":true},"link":"outlet/KA90IVI20R?breadcrumb=","productImage":{"src":"/Product_Shots/{width}x{height}/MCSA00762608_E6797_KA90IVI20G_407519_def.jpg","alt":"KA90IVI20R"},"hookline":"Холодильник coolDuo серии iQ 500 типа \"side-by-side\" с технологией NoFrost, дополнительно оснащен дозатором для воды и льда.","keyBenefits":["Многопоточная ","Технология noFrost .","Холодильник шириной 70см - существенное .","Функция superFreezing .","Функция superCooling."],"pictograms":[{"refId":"14025257","title":"ICON_VITACONTROL","image":"/Feature_Icons/35x35/VITACONTROL_A02_ru-RU.png"},{"refId":"14026934","title":"ICON_SUPERFREEZE","image":"/Feature_Icons/35x35/SUPERFREEZE_A02_ru-RU.png"},{"refId":"14026830","title":"ICON_SUPERCOOLING","image":"/Feature_Icons/35x35/SUPERCOOLING_A02_ru-RU.png"},{"title":"ICON_SEPARATETEMPERATURECONTROL","image":"/Feature_Icons/35x35/SEPARATETEMPERATURECONTROL_A02_ru-RU.png"},{"refId":"14026499","title":"ICON_SAFETYGLASS","image":"/Feature_Icons/35x35/SAFETYGLASS_A02_ru-RU.png"}],"relevance":0.0,"popularity":0,"onlineDate":1579986000,"brandValueClass":"iQ500","brand":"SIEMENS","constructionType":"OTHER","productGroup":"Холодильник Side by Side","turnover_units":0},{

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите в вопрос кусок `HTML`-кода, который парсите, чтобы можно было воспроизвести проблему. Вы можете сделать это, нажав кнопку [edit].

Comment: всё,привел кусок HTML-кода, который парсится в переменную items.

Comment: А это вообще `HTML`? Очень похоже на `JSON`. Думаю, Вы должны парсить его с помощью библиотеки `json`. Это, кстати, очень легко сделать, если Вы использовали `requests`: `d = requests.get(...).json()`.

Comment: вот так будет правильно? s = requests.Session() json_data = s.get(URL, headers=HEADERS, params=None).json()  Print(str( json_data ))